# Having trouble with xna putting its namespace into a .bin list file

Tags: c#, xna

Hi I've made a leveleditor in XNA  that reads and writes a list of custom type tile perfectly within xna however I need to read the .bin into Unity.

I've made the type tile only contain string and int so standard types no `Vector2` or anything XNA related.

The problem I'm having is I get this error:

> Unable to find assembly 'GroupGamelevelEditor, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I get this when reading the .bin file into both unity and just into a quick console application I made to see if it would load and print out the dtails of the list.

It seems that XNA is somehow packaging something to do with the namespace into the list.bin.

Below are 2 methods of writing to the bin that both give the same error when loading into anything but XNA:

Method 1:

```
public List Tile loadTileList(string fileName)   
{
    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();

            var loadedTileList = (List<Tile>)bin.Deserialize(stream);

            return loadedTileList;
        }

    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        List<Tile> l = new List<Tile>();
        return l;
    }
}
```

method 2:

```
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\GroupGameLevelEditor\TestTiles.bin", FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

List<Tile> tiles = (List<Tile>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

return tiles;

stream.Close();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I need this desperately for my final year games programming project at uni.